# How to uninstall OnePica Image CDN Magento extension manually?

Tags: magento, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have deployed an existing site to my local server and the admin and site is loading.

However all the css and js files are not found since the CloudFront CDN is not serving the files to my local server. I have no idea why all the CDN urls are not working.

Hence plan B.

- Since my admin site is not working due to the missing css and js, Does anyone know how I can manually switch off / uninstall the OnePica extension so that I can revert my local copy of the site to reference the local files?

Note that changing the line

```
<active>true</active>
```

to

```
<active>false</active>
```

in the module file OnePica_ImageCdn.xml has made no difference.

Any other tips on manually switching this CDN off??

Comment: After update that xml file, did you refresh or clear the magento cache?

Comment: I cleared the /var/cache/ and /var/session/ and /var/locks/ folder. then hit refresh - the CDN Urls are still being written in the code :[

Comment: If you installed that extension through community, you might remove  or rename that folder in this path : app/code/community/[OnePica]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you got this resolved but I was able to resolve this by changing the configuration scope in the Magento admin and changing the base media url. For me, the cdn url was removed from the Default Config scope but still existed in the "Main Website" config scope.  Here are detailed steps:

1. Navigate to System -> Configuration
2. Change Configuration Scope to "Main Website" from "Default Config"
3. Click on the Web tab
4. Click open the Unsecure and Secure sections
5. Change the text in the "Base Media Url" field to "{{unsecure_base_url}}media/" to the unsecure section and "{{secure_base_url}}media/" to the secure section.
6. Save

Answer (score 0):

Check the media url setting in the Magento admin.

Comment: All media urls are correct - for some reason the css and js are served blank (don't seem to exist), as I am coding the site I need to have the CDN switched off, so I prefer to switch off the CDN locally for now.